# ohmyzsh has an extra symbol in my current git repository

Tags: git, zsh

When I opened a git repository today with my current ohmyzsh theme I see a `⍟2` symbol by the version control info.

I haven't seen this before and a `git status` tells me nothing is wrong.

Doesn't seem like a cause for concern but I would like to know what its trying to tell me. Thanks!

[image]

I'm using the Powerlevel9k theme, the left prompt has this setup:
`POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status load content dir vcs)`

Comment: It would help to know which theme you're using... There's lots of ways the different themes gather VCS information about the directory they are in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That means you have 2 items in your stash. The list of symbols is here:

https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k#vcs

Excerpt of the README without the table formatting that won't work here on SO:

`⍟3` | Number of stashes, here 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to remove that `⍟2` from your terminal you can use the below  command. The meaning of that is that your stash stack has 2 saved commits on the queque, you can pop then to clean it up and reset the head to your most recent commit from your master branch.

***Steps to Clean up your Stash Stack:***

```
git stash pop
git stash pop
git reset --hard HEAD
```